# is it possible to extract the HTML code of a R shiny app such that it can be used without having R?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I´m new to shiny and created an app with some plots. This app now will be used for a presentation and should be easily accesible for other people. So my question is, if and how i can extract the HTML code of a shiny app such that at the end I just have a HTML file with the same stuff which is in my application. 
When I run the app in my browser and do "save as" in the browser, the downloaded HTML doesn´t work like the original application.

Thanks for every answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: no. Shiny apps work with a backend, i.e. a server (which can be running locally on your machine) handling requests, doing some processing, and then sending back the update to the browser. So if you save the HTML, it will only capture the current state, and any interactions will be broken.

However, there are many interactive UI output elements in R that only work with Javascript and don't require shiny. Many of them are based on the htmlwidgets package. Have a look at leaflet (for geospatial data / maps), dygraph (for time-series data), plotly (for nice histograms / scatterplots / etc), and crosstalk (for creating cross-widget interactions without shiny).

Also, a great way to share your work are R Notebooks. These automatically generate a browser-viewable HTML file when you save them.